# ezmesh offsets all z values by over 500

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm using octave's ezmesh to plot a linear regression defined as follows:

```
f = @(x,y) 1 * theta(1) + x * theta(2) + y * theta(3) + x * y * theta(4)
```

For some fixed vector theta:

```
octave:275> theta
theta =

   9.4350e+00
   1.7410e-04
   3.3702e-02
   1.6498e-07
```

I'm using a domain of [0 120000 0 1400], and can evaluate:

```
octave:276> f(0, 0)
ans =  9.4350
octave:277> f(120000, 1400)
ans =  105.23
```

However, if I run:

```
octave:278> ezmesh(f, [0 120000 0 1400])
```

The resulting mesh has a z value of around 570 for (0, 0) and just under 640 for (120000, 1400). I'm baffled. What could be causing this?

EDIT: Even if I simplify f to the following, similar behavior occurs:

```
octave:308> f = @(x, y) (x * y)
```

Why is ezmesh not handling multiplication as expected (by me), so that the function evaluates as I expect, and the values change when the function is used inside of ezmesh?

Comment: I don’t have octave around, but could you try changing `@(x,y) x * y` to `@(x,y) x.* y`?

Comment: It works. Thanks! I guess the lambda is invoked with matrices passed in. Not sure when it would make sense to do matrix multiplication inside a mesh generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ezmesh` invokes the function handle on a matrix of values (to benefit from vectorization performance). Use `.*` for multiplication.